# git commit and pull request separate branches

Tags: git, github

I cloned a repository from master and made some changes to a couple of files. I was asked to commit and create a pull request for each group of changes I have made. For example changes to styles should go in one branch and commit there and have a pull request. Another branch should be changes made to JS files and this has to have its own pull request and branch.

i did `git checkout -b [branchName]` then `git add` only relevant files, then `git commit` and finally `git push --set-upstream origin [branchName]`. When I did this 3 times, it created 3 separate branches but they all shared the same commits and pull requests.

How do I commit and push relevant changes and files to their own branch so that they have their own commit history and pull request?

Comment: any feedback after the answer below?

Comment: I am sure it will work, but I already made the 3 branches and they all have the same commit histories. I need to now somehow make the 3 branches already made only have the commits they were meant to have.

Answer (score 0):

There are two options here:

1. create the 3 branches at the beginning, say `branch1`, `branch2`,
   `branch3`
2. do a `git checkout branch1`, make changes, do `git add` and
   then a `git commit`
3. create a pull request for `branch1`
4. go back to point (2) but in this case use `branch2` (and do the same for `branch3`)

the second option is the following. Suppose you start from `master`.

1. create `branch1` with `checkout -b`
2. make changes, do `git add`, do `git commit`
3. create pull request for the branch
4. do a `git checkout master` (so go back in history)
5. go back to point (1) but in this case use `branch2` (same for `branch3`)

Comment: It is also possible to `git checkout -b branch2 master` to make a new branch based on master. This would save the step to checkout master everytime.